# CORS issue on Cloudfront

Tags: node.js, express, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I keep getting CORS error on AWS Cloudfront even though i have tried the `curl -H "Origin: app.xxx.ai" -v "https://d2dmfwb9k858np.cloudfront.net/nAQAwbZy56.png"`

< access-control-allow-origin: *

< access-control-allow-methods: PUT, POST, DELETE, GET

[image]

Thinking it may has something to do with this. Have anyone faced this issue before?

[image]

I have this code in my Express.js back-end.

```
    this.app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp")
      res.header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "cross-origin")
      res.header("Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy", "cross-origin")
      res.set('Cache-control', `no-store`)
      next()
    })
```

This is the Cloudfront behavior:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it on Cloudfront.

Cloudfront => Edit behavior => Allowed HTTP methods

[image]

Also, check on the app Express
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: I just updated the question - I've done it before